# How to validate embed tag?

Tags: php, html, security, validation, embed

I'm allowing users to embed content from `youtube`, `vimeo`, `scribd`, `flickr`, `slideshare`, etc. and therefore i'm allowing them to paste the embed code in a textbox.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to:

> (a) validate that its indeed a correctly formed embed code and
>   (b) whether its not any malicious code that the user is trying to get my
>   system to display.

This is a php website.

Comment: Is there some reason they are able to write the whole embed?  What about only accepting width/height and the embed URL?  You might even be able to generate the embed URL from parsing a direct link.

Comment: @OverZealous  - no... how do other sites do this? Is there a standardized way of tackling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will be implementing a system where we ask the user to specify the direct URL and we go and subsequently fetch appropriate data from that page.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) in the past. There are some others, but this one worked the best for me. You can whitelist all allowed code constructs and make the html code standard compliant. It's a good first line of defense against XXS attacks.

The library is quite big and can slow down your code if you don't install it correctly, so read the install docs carefully.

Comment: Hi - not sure if that's what i would be looking for - have you used this specifically for embed code?